# FindOne inside map returns no results

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a search using FindOne inside map but it never finds the data by Product Id. I don't understand the reason. Im using express on nodejs.

This is my code:

```
const calc =  (details) => { 
    
    let grandSubtotal = 0; 

    details.map( async detail  => { 

        const {verifyProduct} = await Product.find({ _id: detail._id}); 

        console.log(detail._id);
        console.log(verifyProduct); // UNDEFINED

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
const result = await Promise.all(details.map( async (detail) => { … } ));
```

when you do it like you done you will get a pending promise object that never going to be resolved, I don’t know if you want to return some results, if no just do await Promise.all

Also this should be:

```
const calc = async (details) => { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose [`find`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find) returns a list of results. [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOne) returns an object.

The code is doing the equivalent of:

```
const {verifyProduct} = []
```

Use `findOne` to get an object to destructure, and test the result before use.

```
    details.map( async (detail) => { 
        const res = await Product.findOne({ _id: detail._id }); 
        if (!res) {
          //throw new Error('No id '.detail._id)
          console.log('No id', detail._id)
        }
        const { verifyProduct } = res

        console.log(detail._id);
        console.log(verifyProduct);
    }
```

Also (as @antokhio noted), if you want to use the returned result array of the `details.map` you will need to `await` those as well.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need await here

```
Product.find(({ _id }) =>  _id === detail._id );
```